# Spring fox dependency does not resolve the error when upgrading to Springboot 3.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, upgrade, startup, springfox

There is a micro-service, which is implemented on top of Springboot 2.5.8 and it is required to be upgraded to Springboot 3.1.0. During the upgrade the following error was shown when starting up the application.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
```

In order to resolve this, the following changes were done but still the error is there. Can anyone has come across this situation?

1. Updated dependencies needed for swagger (previously it was spring-fox 2.9.2 version)

   ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
       <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Added the following configuration in application.yml and checked

   spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher

However, none of the above solutions didn't resolve the above issue. Does anyone has come across this situation and found answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `springfox-boot-starter` version `3.0.0` lacks compatibility with Spring Boot 3. Consider switching to [SpringDoc v2](https://springdoc.org/v2/) which does support it and is actively maintained.

Comment: Thank you @birca123. I went through the document and it the newest version supports Java 17 / Springboot 3.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following spring-doc dependency solved the issue.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

PS: There should be spring-boot-starter-web dependency, as a prerequisite of the above.